# How to get array size input using S-function builder

Tags: matlab, simulink, builder, s-function

I am using MATLAB2014b s-function builder and I would like to get the size of my input array.
For example, I have the following input.
Name: A, dimension: 2, Row: 1, Column: 16, Real

In the output pane, I wrote the following code in order to get the array size.

```
size_t size_1 = sizeof(A)/sizeof(real_T);
```

When I output "size_1" in my Simulink model, I obtain "1", I am expecting the result to be 16. Is my code wrong ? Is there a way to get the input array size ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is `length(A)`. Matlab is cleverer than C/C++ in handling multidimensional arrays. It even does intelligent things when you are assigning a column vector to a row vector, it knows what you want to do.